# Change seqID and remove a part after a pattern

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I actually have fasta files such:

```
>seq1:QXQXQWQ:XQWQ
ACTG
>seq3:WCCWHWJ:WGH
ATGC
>seq7:GCGC:G
ATGACA
```

and I would like to remove all thing after the first ":" and get:

```
>seq1
ACTG
>seq3
ATGC
>seq7
ATGACA
```

And this with biopython if it is possible?

Comment: `string.split(':')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Simple in biopython with `SeqIO`, just modify `record.id` and `record.description`, by splitting the string appropriately:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def yield_records(in_file):
    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta'):
        record.description = record.id = record.id.split(':', 1)[0]
        yield record

SeqIO.write(yield_records('in.fasta'), 'out.fasta', 'fasta')
```